# Этимология слова "Китай"

Tags: этимология, топонимика

Откуда в русском языке взялось названием страны "Китай", если на том же английском звучит China?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Английский здесь не аргумент.
По-китайски, т. е. на кантонском диалекте, который обычно называют собственно китайским, Китай звучит примерно как "Чжуньгво", на других диалектах — ещё более экзотически.

Все европейские названия Китая происходят в общем-то от случайных топонимов, этнонимов или этнохоронимов (названия мест, племен или жителей определённой местности), многие восходят к латинизированному "Cina" — возможно, от названия местности на севере современного Китая.

Русское же "Китай" по Фасмеру происходит от самоназвания тунгусо-манчжурской народности "K'atyn", завоевавшей Китай в X веке.

(+)====
30.01.2017
Меня поправили в отношении кантонского диалекта. Может и не кантонский, не принципиально.

Послушать же можно здесь:
[**Китай** | translate.google.ru](https://translate.google.ru/#ru/zh-TW/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9)

Я слышу примерно как "Чуньгво" или "Чунгво" (с носовым Н).

К вопросу этимологии русского названия "Китай" не относится никак.

Comment: "По-китайски, т.е. на кантонском диалекте, который обычно называют собственно китайским", это очень странная фраза. Китайским обычно называют мандарин, путунхуа, северный диалект. Уж точно не кантонский.

Comment: @aughedelic Спасибо. Я не китаист, да и обсуждения этого вопроса скорее всего вызовет нарекания модератора (послал Бог за грехи наши). Но если коротко, то тут, видимо, недоразумение в понимании моей фразы. Я не утверждал такого, что кантонский - это мандарин. А северные наречия (путунхуа)  называюют именно мандарин, не китайскими. Кантонский - один из известных и распространенных диалектов. Остальное - к делу не относится.

Comment: Вы можете обсудить это в чате.

Comment: Есть мнение, что China всё же происходит от названия династии Чин, которая правила Китаем в древности.

Answer (score 3):

Есть мнение, что слово «Китай» произошло от названия племени кидани, которое жило в северном Китае. В других западноевропейских языках это слово появилось от названия «Катай» (Catai, и т. д.), которое Марко Поло дал стране во время своего путешествия в Азию.

Answer (score 0):

Китай - это древнее слово. Сейчас уже не понять, из какого языка оно взялось, действительно, означает что-то обнесенное стеной. И в английском языке есть слово, родственное ему это City-город, как и в итальянском citta (читта) тоже город, в центре Парижа есть остров, называется он Ситэ или Сите, и он, как это достоверно известно, был когда-то обнесен стеной. Есть на латыни Civitas-город. Города-то раньше стеной обносили. Отсюда и слово цитадель тоже и т. д.

Answer (score 0):

Не берусь утверждать точно, но хочу обратить внимание на башкирскую народность **катайцы**. Эти племена — пришельцы на Южный Урал и Зауралье.
**Катай** этнически восходит к монгольским и тюркским племенам Центр. и Ср. Азии, Юж. Сибири и Алтая. Этноним «катай» известен у гагаузов, казахов, каракалпаков, киргизов, узбеков. Первоначально они жили где-то за Байкалом, ближе к Монголии, потом переместились западнее. В районе Семиречья было их государство, завоёванное потом Чингиз-ханом.
Есть версия, что первоначально **катайцы** были монголоязычны, но подверглись тюркизации. На Урал они попали в XIII веке. На территории Южного Урала **катайцы** оставили немало топонимических следов. Кроме Усть-Катава и Катав-Ивановска еще: в Ашинском районе — Катайские горы, а в Нязепетровске — Катайская гора. Восточнее, в Чебаркульском районе, отыщется озеро Катай-куль, а еще восточнее, в Красноармейском районе — озеро Катай и Катайское болото. Наконец, в Курганской области (Зауралье) — город Катайск.
Возможно, первоначально занимаемая **катайцами** территория (у северной границы современного Китая) и послужила на Руси названием для страны КИТАЙ .